# Standalone PGP Text Encryption Application

Tags: windows, encryption, portable, pgp

I am looking for a standalone executable that facilitates PGP encryption of files or plaintext (plaintext can be dumped into a ".txt" file and encrypted).

I have heard that [PortablePGP](http://ppgp.sourceforge.net) is [unsafe](https://www.deepdotweb.com/security-tutorials/word-warning-versions-pgp-created-equally/).

> **Versions of PGP  that should make you run away screaming:**
>
> Versions of PGP with these Version: strings are based on the BouncyCastle Java crypto libraries. They should be avoided like the plague.
>
> Version: BCPG v1.45
>
> Version: BCPG v1.47

Comment: The article you linked to complains that the default key sizes of these versions is too small. So, you could just increase the key size if that's an option.

Comment: @Kodiologist I got the impression that the "BouncyCastle" library being used had vulnerabilities. Why else would they mention the library? Wouldn't an unsafe default key size be a criticism of the program/application rather than the version?

Comment: The claim is that these versions of PGP have a small default key size because they're implemented with Bouncy Castle, and Bouncy Castle has a small default key size.

Comment: @Kodiologist want to write an answer?

Comment: @sebix I don't know the answer.

Comment: What's wrong with plain GPG? Maybe the OP should explain the *exact* requirements.